# Java - extends why the super variable a is 0

Tags: java, extend

Please look at this code:

```
class Sup {
    int a = 8;

    public void printA() {
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    Sup() {
        printA();
    }
}

public class Sub extends Sup {
    int a = 9;

    @Override
    public void printA() {
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    Sub() {
        printA();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sub sub = new Sub();
    }
}
```

result：
console print：  `0  9` 
I know that subclass will first calls the superclass `constructor`
but ,why is the `0 9`  , not `8 9`?

Comment: Are you sure the constructor is called in the order you think it is?

Comment: @cricket_007: Of course it's called. You **cannot** avoid calling it in Java.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You can avoid it by using serialization or cloning.

Comment: @Flown: Meh, the super constructor's been called at *some point* in both those cases. :-D

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You're right in terms of the already existing objects.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3404301/2513200

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When the `Sup` constructor calls `printA()` it executes the `printA` method of class `Sub` (which overrides the method of the same name of class `Sup`), so it returns the value of the `a` variable of class `Sub`, which is still `0`, since the instance variables of `Sub` are not yet initialized (they are only initialized after the `Sup` constructor is done).

Comment: This is also why some code standards require all methods called in constructors to be `final` or `private`. To prevent overrides causing these situations.